# Python: loading txt file into 2d list of different types

Tags: python

I have a 2d list saved in a text file that looks like this (showing the first 2 entries):

```
('9b7dad', "text", 'http://imgur.com/gallery/SPdGm27', '1', 'A', 5)
('2b6ebj', 'text2', 'https://i.redd.it/lzft358csdi21.jpg', '1', 'B', 6)
```

How should this be loaded into a list? (so for example `list[0][0] = '9b7dad'`, `list[1][1] = 'text2'` etc)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
f = open(<your file path>)
result = [
    [g.replace("'", "")
     for g in l.strip('()\n').replace(' ', '').replace('"', '').split(',')]
    for l in f.readlines()]

f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a text file with each line in the form you've shown:

```
('9b7dad', "text", 'http://imgur.com/gallery/SPdGm27', '1', 'A', 5)    
('2b6ebj', 'text2', 'https://i.redd.it/lzft358csdi21.jpg', '1', 'B', 6)
```

You can use Pandas which offers a more straightforward way to handle/manipulate different data types.

Import pandas and read in the file, here called 'stack.txt':

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('stack.txt', sep=",", header=None)
```

Returns only the list of list:

```
alist = data.values.tolist()
```

Print to check:

```
print(alist)

[['9b7dad', 'text', 'http://imgur.com/gallery/SPdGm27', '1', 'A', 5], 
 ['2b6ebj', 'text2', 'https://i.redd.it/lzft358csdi21.jpg', '1', 'B', 6]]
```

If need to process columns:

```
for i in range(len(data.columns)):
    if i == 0:
        data[i] = data[i].map(lambda x: str(x)[1:])
        data[i] = data[i].map(lambda x: str(x)[1:-1])
    if i == 5:
        data[i] = data[i].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-1])
        data[i] = data[i].astype(int)
    if 0 < i < 5:
        data[i] = data[i].map(lambda x: str(x)[2:-1])
```

Comment: welcome, You should not  process columns....  then all you is have is  >>> alist = data.values.tolist()

Comment: I may not understand your point, however in this case processing columns allows for desirable formatting of the raw data in the .txt file.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying that for me. I deemed it a better solution but will be more precise next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

myList = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    elems = line.strip('()\n').replace(' ', '').split(',')
    elems = [x.strip('\'\"') for x in elems]
    myList.append(elems)

print(myList[0][0])
print(myList[1][1])
```

To use:

```
$ python ./load.py < someText.txt
9b7dad
text2
```

Use `int()`, `float()`, or `str()` to coerce fields in `elems` to certain types, as needed. Use a `try..except` block to catch malformed input.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast

with open(file_name) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [list(ast.literal_eval(x)) for x in content]
```

How to read files:
[In Python, how do I read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/in-python-how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

More about eval:
[Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Answer (score 0):

try this (converting tuple to list):

```
my_list = []
my_list.append(list('9b7dad', "text", 'http://imgur.com/gallery/SPdGm27', '1', 'A', 5))
my_list.append(list('2b6ebj', 'text2', 'https://i.redd.it/lzft358csdi21.jpg', '1', 'B', 6))
```

result is a list of lists i.e. a 2 dimensional list. You can easily modify the code to fetch a line at a time in a for loop and append it to the list. Consider using split(',') if it is a comma separated list instead of a tuple e.g.

```
mylist = []
with open(filename, 'r') as my_file:
   for text in my_file.readlines()
       my_list.append(text.split(','))
```