# Python: loading txt file with only 1 line into 2d list of different types

Tags: python

I have a 2d list saved in a text file that looks like this (showing the first 3 entries):

```
('9b7rfs', "29sdf dfs fdf sdf", 'http://imgur.com/gallery/SDsGdO7', '29', 'M', 1)('9b73bj', 'quick brown fox', 'https://i.redd.it/lfhg348cszi11.jpg', '18', 'M', 5)('9b418d', 'third string', 'https://imgur.com/a/DddTo6E', '36', 'm', 6)
```

I want this to be loaded into a list so for example `list[0][0] = '9b7rfs'`, `list[1][1] = 'quick brown fox'` etc. Each item in the list is separated by brackets. I had posted a similar question ([Python: loading txt file into 2d list of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52094014/python-loading-txt-file-into-2d-list-of-different-types)) but could not get any of the solutions to work. Everything is actually on the same line and I need the text to remain with spaces.

Comment: You should not save something so ugly. You should try csv (remove the "()" and add line breaks). Reading a csv is something much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
data = []
with open('input.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        data.append(line.strip('()\n').split(','))

print(data[0][0])
print(data[1][1])
```

**Output**

```
'9b7rfs'
 'quick brown fox'
```

**Notes**

This answer assumes the text file is named `'input.txt'` and is in the same directory as the `.py` file. Also the format assumes one tuple per line, like this:

```
('9b7rfs', "29sdf dfs fdf sdf", 'http://imgur.com/gallery/SDsGdO7', '29', 'M', 1)
('9b73bj', 'quick brown fox', 'https://i.redd.it/lfhg348cszi11.jpg', '18', 'M', 5)
('9b418d', 'third string', 'https://imgur.com/a/DddTo6E', '36', 'm', 6)
```

Also this will give you strings like `'quick brown fox'` (with a space upfront). If you want to remove those spaces change the line in the for loop to:

```
data.append([element.strip() for element in  line.strip('()\n').split(',')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all that's preventing the content of the text file from being a valid Pyton expression are the missing commas between the parentheses, you can simply use the `str.replace()` method to fill in the commas and pass the resulting string to `ast.literal_eval()` to turn it into a tuple of tuples:

```
import ast
s = '''('9b7rfs', "29sdf dfs fdf sdf", 'http://imgur.com/gallery/SDsGdO7', '29', 'M', 1)('9b73bj', 'quick brown fox', 'https://i.redd.it/lfhg348cszi11.jpg', '18', 'M', 5)('9b418d', 'third string', 'https://imgur.com/a/DddTo6E', '36', 'm', 6)'''
print(ast.literal_eval(s.replace(')(', '),(')))
```

This outputs:

```
(('9b7rfs', '29sdf dfs fdf sdf', 'http://imgur.com/gallery/SDsGdO7', '29', 'M', 1), ('9b73bj', 'quick brown fox', 'https://i.redd.it/lfhg348cszi11.jpg', '18', 'M', 5), ('9b418d', 'third string', 'https://imgur.com/a/DddTo6E', '36', 'm', 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use CSV files, if you have large number of entities.

```
data = open(r'data.txt','r')
list_2d = [j[1:].split(',') for j in a.split(')')]
print(list_2d[1][1])
print(list_2d[1][1])
```

out:

```
'9b7rfs'
 'quick brown fox'
```